# Grab text from span and then compare it using CodeceptJS

Tags: variables, codeceptjs

I have this in source on one page:

```
<span class="price-length price-length--4">666</span>
```

And I have this in source on another page

```
<span class="price-length price-length--7">777</span>
```

I want to grab that 666 value, store it somewhere, and compare to 777. How to do that using codeceptjs?

I tried `I.grabValueFrom('some_xpath_to_value')`, but I don't understand how to reuse it. How to see value that `I.grabValueFrom` function returns in codeceptjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator function to return values via 'yield' from functions like so:

```
Scenario('Yield', function* (I) {
  let value = yield I.grabValueFrom(some_xpath_to_value);


  let assert = require('assert');
  assert.equal(value, '777');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

All functions in Codeceptjs return Promises, not values.
So to get value from `I.grab...` functions, you should get Promise result.

You can use Garret solution with `yield`.
Or the same, but with `async`/`await` (required for Codecept Node.js 8.9.1 have `async`/`await` support)

```
const assert = require('assert');

Scenario('async', async function(I) {
  let value = await I.grabValueFrom(some_xpath_to_value);

  assert.equal(value, '777');
});
```

Comment: Rinat Makhmutov answer is more up-to-date. It uses `({I})=>` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use the console to check the grab method:

```
import assert from "assert";

Scenario("Example", async ({ I }) => {
  const firstValue = await I.grabValueFrom("some_xpath_to_value");
  console.log(firstValue);
  const secondValue = await I.grabValueFrom("some_xpath_to_value");
  console.log(secondValue);

  assert.ok(firstValue == secondValue, `Values don't match`);
});
```